# Split rows into multiple while keeping other data

Tags: google-sheets, split, aggregate

In Google Sheets I have table like the following

| Home Player 1 | Home Player 2 | Away Player 1 | Away Player 2 | Home Goals | Away Goals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ronaldo | Messi | Neymar | Aguero | 2 | 1 |
| Aguero | Ronaldo | Neymar | Messi | 1 | 1 |
| Messi | Aguero | Ronaldo | Neymar | 0 | 2 |

I need to aggregate the Players columns into one column and show how many goals each player's team has scored.

The final table would look like this:

| Player | Goals |
| --- | --- |
| Ronaldo | 5 |
| Messi | 3 |
| Neymar | 4 |
| Aguero | 2 |

What formula can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
=query({A2:A,E2:E; B2:B,E2:E; C2:C,F2:F; D2:D,F2:F}, "Select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 <>'' group by Col1 order by sum(Col2) desc label Col1 'Player', sum(Col2) 'Goals'", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, apparently it doesn't recognise the curly brackets representing a group of data and it returns an error

Comment: In Italy you have tu use `\` in place of `,`

Comment: I managed to solve it, thank you! But now it says there's an error in the query "NO_COLUMN: Col2"

Comment: Here is the syntax for Italy : `=query({A2:A\E2:E; B2:B\E2:E; C2:C\F2:F; D2:D\F2:F}; "Select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 <>'' group by Col1 order by sum(Col2) desc label Col1 'Player', sum(Col2) 'Goals'"; 0)`